# User-defined parameters in stored procedure are not calculating data

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I am creating a stored procedure for an SSRS report and normally when I have a multi-valued parameter, I use a split function to separate and calculate the results.

But my issue with this stored procedure is that I have three additional values I need to add to the data set; which I have done here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.rpt_DataSet_AgentClassType
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT   
        x.ID, x.ClassType
    FROM     
        (SELECT 997 AS [ID], 'Desktops' AS [ClassType]
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 998 AS [ID], 'Mobile Devices' AS [ClassType]
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 999 AS [ID], 'Mobile Apps' AS [ClassType]
         UNION ALL

         SELECT ACT.[id] AS [ID], ACT.[description] AS [ClassType]
         FROM dbo.AgentClassTypes AS [ACT]
         WHERE ACT.id NOT IN (14, 15, 16)
           AND ACT.active = 1
     ) AS x
ORDER BY 
    x.ID;
END;
```

The resulting data set looks like:

```
ID   ClassType
--------------------------------
1    TWRA Central License Sales
3    General Agent
4    Service Desk
5    Internet
....
18   State Parks
19   TWRA Special
997  Desktops
998  Mobile Devices
999  Mobile Apps
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is that if the user selects 997 - Desktops, 998 - Mobile Devices, or 999 - Mobiles Apps; the stored procedure should not use the split function since the value does not exist in the table, but search a specific field in a table for the data set.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.rpt_HarvestByAgentType
    @StartDate DATE,
    @EndDate DATE,
    @AgentClassType VARCHAR(MAX),
    @SpeciesID VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HarvestByAgentTypeResults') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #HarvestByAgentTypeResults;

    CREATE TABLE #HarvestByAgentTypeResults
    (
         TotalHarvest INT,
         HarvestDate DATE,
         AgentClassType VARCHAR(100),
         SpeciesID INT,
         SpeciesType VARCHAR(50)
    );

    -- Desktops
    IF @AgentClassType IN ('997')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #HarvestByAgentTypeResults (TotalHarvest, HarvestDate, AgentClassType, SpeciesID, SpeciesType)
            SELECT  
                COUNT(x.HarvestRecordID) AS [TotalHarvest],
                x.HarvestDate AS [HarvestDate],
                'Desktop' AS [AgentClassType],
                x.SpeciesID AS [SpeciesID],
                x.SpeciesType AS [SpeciesType]
            FROM    
                (SELECT    
                     CHR.HarvestRecordID,
                     CAST(CHR.HarvestDate AS DATE) AS [HarvestDate],
                     CHR.SpeciesID AS [SpeciesID],
                     HST.SpeciesType AS SpeciesType
                 FROM      
                     dbo.CustomerHarvestReports AS [CHR]
                 INNER JOIN 
                     dbo.Agents AS [A] ON A.agentID = CHR.agentID
                 INNER JOIN 
                     dbo.AgentClassTypes AS [ACT] ON ACT.id = A.agentClassTypeID
                 INNER JOIN 
                     dbo.HarvestSpeciesTypes AS [HST] ON HST.SpeciesID = CHR.SpeciesID AND HST.InActive = 0
                 WHERE     
                     CHR.HarvestDate >= @StartDate
                     AND CHR.HarvestDate <= @EndDate
                     AND HST.SpeciesID In (SELECT Item 
                                           FROM dbo.fnSplit(@SpeciesID,','))
                     AND CHR.isInvalidated = 0
                     AND ((CHR.httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Win%' AND CHR.httpUserAgentString NOT LIKE '%Windows Phone%' )  --  Windows Machines excluding Windows phones
                           OR (CHR.httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Linux%' AND CHR.httpUserAgentString NOT LIKE '%Android')  -- Linux machines excluding Android phones
                           OR CHR.httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Macintosh%' -- Mac books
                           OR CHR.httpUserAgentString LIKE '%CrOS%') -- Chrome Books
                ) x
            GROUP BY 
                x.HarvestDate, x.SpeciesID, x.SpeciesType
    END;
    -- Mobile Devices
    ELSE IF @AgentClassType IN ('998')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #HarvestByAgentTypeResults(TotalHarvest, HarvestDate, AgentClassType, SpeciesID, SpeciesType)
            SELECT  
                COUNT(x.HarvestRecordID) AS [TotalHarvest],
                x.HarvestDate AS [HarvestDate],
                'MobileDevice' AS [AgentClassType] ,
                x.SpeciesID AS [SpeciesID] ,
                x.SpeciesType AS [SpeciesType]
    FROM    ( SELECT    CHR.HarvestRecordID ,
                        CAST(CHR.HarvestDate AS DATE) AS [HarvestDate] ,
                        ACT.[description] agentClass ,
                        CHR.SpeciesID AS [SpeciesID] ,
                        HST.SpeciesType AS SpeciesType
              FROM      dbo.CustomerHarvestReports AS [CHR]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Agents AS [A] ON A.agentID = CHR.agentID
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AgentClassTypes AS [ACT] ON ACT.id = A.agentClassTypeID
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HarvestSpeciesTypes AS [HST] ON HST.SpeciesID = CHR.SpeciesID AND HST.InActive = 0
              WHERE     CHR.HarvestDate >= @StartDate
                        AND CHR.HarvestDate <= @EndDate
                        AND HST.SpeciesID In ( SELECT Item FROM dbo.fnSplit(@SpeciesID,','))
                        AND CHR.isInvalidated = 0
                        AND (( httpUserAgentString LIKE '%iPhone%' AND httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Version%' ) -- iPhones
                        OR ( httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Android%' AND httpUserAgentString NOT LIKE '%Version%' ) -- Androids
                        OR ( httpUserAgentString LIKE '%iPad%' AND httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Version%' ) -- iPads
                        OR ( httpUserAgentString LIKE '%BB10%' )  -- Blackberries
                        OR ( httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Windows Phone%' )) -- Windows Phones
            ) x
    GROUP BY x.HarvestDate ,
            x.SpeciesID ,
            x.SpeciesType
END;

-- Mobile Apps
ELSE IF @AgentClassType IN ('999')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #HarvestByAgentTypeResults
            ( TotalHarvest ,
              HarvestDate ,
              AgentClassType ,
              SpeciesID ,
              SpeciesType
            )
    SELECT  COUNT(x.HarvestRecordID) AS [TotalHarvest] ,
            x.HarvestDate AS [HarvestDate],
            'MobileApp' AS [AgentClassType] ,
            x.SpeciesID AS [SpeciesID] ,
            x.SpeciesType AS [SpeciesType]
    FROM    ( SELECT    CHR.HarvestRecordID ,
                        CAST(CHR.HarvestDate AS DATE) AS [HarvestDate] ,
                        ACT.[description] agentClass ,
                        CHR.SpeciesID AS [SpeciesID] ,
                        HST.SpeciesType AS SpeciesType
              FROM      dbo.CustomerHarvestReports AS [CHR]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Agents AS [A] ON A.agentID = CHR.agentID
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AgentClassTypes AS [ACT] ON ACT.id = A.agentClassTypeID
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HarvestSpeciesTypes AS [HST] ON HST.SpeciesID = CHR.SpeciesID AND HST.InActive = 0
              WHERE     CHR.HarvestDate >= @StartDate
                        AND CHR.HarvestDate <= @EndDate
                        AND HST.SpeciesID In ( SELECT Item FROM dbo.fnSplit(@SpeciesID,','))
                        AND CHR.isInvalidated = 0
                        AND (( httpUserAgentString LIKE '%iPhone%' AND httpUserAgentString NOT LIKE '%Version%' AND httpUserAgentString NOT LIKE '%Windows Phone%' ) -- iPhones
                        OR ( httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Android%' AND httpUserAgentString LIKE '%Version%' )) -- Androids
            ) x
    GROUP BY x.HarvestDate ,
            x.SpeciesID ,
            x.SpeciesType
END;

ELSE IF (@AgentClassType NOT IN ('997','998','999'))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #HarvestByAgentTypeResults
            ( TotalHarvest ,
              HarvestDate ,
              AgentClassType ,
              SpeciesID ,
              SpeciesType
            )
   SELECT COUNT(x.HarvestRecordID) AS [TotalHarvest] ,
    x.HarvestDate AS [HarvestDate] ,
     x.AgentTypeClass AS [AgentTypeClass] ,
     x.SpeciesID AS [SpeciesID] ,
     x.SpeciesType AS [SpeciesType]      
FROM     (   SELECT CHR.HarvestRecordID ,
                CAST(CHR.HarvestDate AS DATE) AS [HarvestDate] ,
                ACT.[description] AS [AgentTypeClass] ,
                CHR.SpeciesID AS [SpeciesID] ,
                HST.SpeciesType AS [SpeciesType]
         FROM   dbo.CustomerHarvestReports AS [CHR]
                INNER JOIN dbo.Agents AS [A] ON A.agentID = CHR.agentID
                INNER JOIN dbo.AgentClassTypes AS [ACT] ON ACT.id = A.agentClassTypeID
                INNER JOIN dbo.HarvestSpeciesTypes AS [HST] ON HST.SpeciesID = CHR.SpeciesID AND HST.InActive = 0
         WHERE  CHR.HarvestDate >= @StartDate
                AND CHR.HarvestDate <= @EndDate
                AND HST.SpeciesID IN ( SELECT Item FROM   dbo.fnSplit(@SpeciesID, ','))
                AND A.agentClassTypeID IN ( SELECT Item FROM dbo.fnSplit(@AgentClassType ,','))
                AND CHR.isInvalidated = 0
     ) AS x
GROUP BY x.HarvestDate ,
     x.AgentTypeClass ,
     x.SpeciesID ,
     x.SpeciesType
ORDER BY x.HarvestDate ,
     x.AgentTypeClass,
     x.SpeciesType;
END

SELECT TotalHarvest ,
   HarvestDate ,
   AgentClassType ,
   SpeciesID ,
   SpeciesType FROM #HarvestByAgentTypeResults
ORDER BY HarvestDate, SpeciesType, AgentClassType;

DROP TABLE #HarvestByAgentTypeResults;

END;
```

When I execute the stored procedure from Management Studio, if I only input 997 or 998 or 999 in the `@AgentClasstype` variable, I get results. But if I include values such as 1, 3, 5, etc... - then the data set I would expect from 997, 998, or 999 are not returned.

Hopefully I have explained this clearly - it has been difficult to script correctly and seemingly - just as hard to write up for help.

Comment: Send through a comma delimnated list to your proc. Use a split method to insert each id into it's own row in a table then process all the IDs in the table . Use a case statement so when @AgentClassType = 997 THEN DO something and another for 998  and 999. use the else for all the other values.

Comment: OK - so I should insert the values the user selects from the AgentClassType parameter into a table, and then JOIN to the table, and then use a CASE statement in the WHERE clause if I am understanding your suggestion correctly.